# Strange symbols in /var/log/auth.log

Tags: ubuntu, security, authentication, ubuntu-12.04, log-files

I just installed fail2ban after realizing that there were tenthousands of attempts to log into one of our servers over SSH.

After installing fail2ban, the log bloat stopped, but I still wanted to check the log files to see if any attempt was successfull - and noticed something strange: If I attempt to scroll through the files or use cat, my whole console is broken, after displaying a loooong series of unrecognized characters - things like:

```
K��|�
��yj�]���t]��f\|�JkW.b�+t��v�u�l�v-���%��]K���ׂ+�Ye��G���2W�kׂ�[s6ǵ1{Ë�Ïf׵~ׂ+�9���E,pŮ�&�����5�p"D��P}�\�_�vb+���*NW�PZ�5�p�D�yM�}��Z��I9�kcN5p�"��jc   ����q���?͹���5�5\a'f :�r\�+Qŵ2)S\���2ufS��up];|���`QJ����ؕj�g��TK
�7q�sw��v�x�%���jq
���Y�5X�           \�+�T+   �2�5efo�4���q����n\+�rZTR�="�Ǖ����VŃ1�q�Uq�g�I�D����qm̩�T�WxRQ
Kz5L���J׵Q���j������
```

(I even had to remove some simbols here since serverfault didn't let me submit it)

Since I used `cat` to print them (I wanted to use `cat ... | grep Accepted` to find every accepted attempt) now my console is broken as well:

`Å0;rootÄlvpsxx-xx-xxx-xxx: ürootÄlvpsxx-xx-xxx-xxx:ü#`

(I added the 'xx')

Did I accidentally execute some sort of malicious code while using `cat /var/log/auth.log`? Is that even posible? And how can I analyze this kind of file, even even nano completly breaks (all characters on the screen are suddenly broken when reaching a certain spot - including UI) when scrolling through it?

Comment: When in doubt, use "file" to validate the file type.  e.g. file /var/log/*  Then pass the file through "strings -a" to remove no printable text.  e.g. strings -a /var/log/auth.log | more  You may also want to review your syslog configuration to determine if someone enabled the writing of compressed log files but gave it the wrong name.  Rsyslog can write gzip compressed files on the fly, but it is up to the sysadmin to choose a name that ends in .gz.

Answer (score 2):

There were probably some control characters that file (which appears to be binary, not text.  Maybe it is a zipped file that you cat'ed by mistake?) which altered the character set of your terminal.  Logging out and back in should fix the character issue.  As for the file, make sure you did not cat a binary file by mistake.  If it ends in .bz or .gz, it is bzipped (or gzipped).

Comment: It could also be a problem with unicode characters.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649896/why-doesnt-my-terminal-output-unicode-characters-properly

Comment: In bash, you can issue the `reset` command to get again the right charset for your terminal without closing/opening (or ssh disconnecting/connecting)
Try first Ctrl+C to avoid having anything typed already as you won't be able to see what you type

regarding the log, check what kind of file is, with `file /var/log/auth.log`
Per default it shoudn't be zipped nor binary

Comment: As far as I can tell it's a normal text file: everything works fine for a while (for example, in nano) and then suddenly everything breaks while scrolling through it. There are older log files which are .gz, but I didn't open those.

Comment: It sounds like it might be a unicode character or a character in a different character set.